# C++ Identifying Classes based on an ID

Tags: c++

Okay, so I'm making a tile-based game, and I am loading a world from a file. So I get an array of about 100 x 15 chars, with each char representing the ID of a tile. Say I have 32 types of tiles, each with special properties. They all inherit from a Tile class, and they each have an ID 0-31. I want to create a Tile array of 100 x 15 tiles, and the other array with the chars will tell me which tiles to put where. But basically, how can I most efficiently figure out which tile the ID belongs to?

Say, I just read a char and it is 3, which correlates to some tile "D".
So, should I do this type thing:

```
switch(idFromChar)
case 0: tile A
case 1: tile B
case 2: tile C
case 3: tile D
```

That seems slow to me though, having to do that potentially a lot. Like if I have 1000 tile in a level, and 255 types of tiles, that's 255000 checks to load the level. I was hoping for something like somehow an array, of Tile classes. As in:

```
tileClassArray[0] = A
tileClassArray[1] = B
```

and so on...

That way, I could just call:

```
(tileClassArray[IDFromChar])(parameters)
```

as a constructor, without having to loop through each Tile class. But I don't know how to make an array of classes, or if it is possible.

Do you get what I'm trying to say? Any help would be nice.

Comment: I think you mean `(tileClassArray[i])(parameters)`, right?

Comment: I don't see why a switch would be worse than your array. If you have 1000 tiles then using a switch you'll get 1000 checks. A switch will check all your possibilities at once, just like using an array, it will not check each possibility one at a time.

Comment: This question seems to be about optimisation but I think your approaching that prematurely.  Do you know what you will do many times and what you will do only a few? Loading a level 1, using a level N?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, you can't store constructors. You'll have to make a template function to create an object, then store pointers to that, then you can call that function through the index.

```
class Tile { ... }; // base class
class TileA : public Tile { ... };
class TileB : public Tile { ... };
class TileC : public Tile { ... };
...

template<typename T>
Tile* createTile() {
    return new T;
};

typedef Tile*(*TileCreator)();

TileCreator creationFuncs[] = {
    &createTile<TileA>,
    &createTile<TileB>,
    &createTile<TileC>,
    ....
};

Tile* newTile = (creationFuncs[type])();
```

However, I can't think of a way to do this that won't be `O(n)` efficiency with regards to typing :)

Comment: You don't have to create a `template` function, there are other ways to load the creation methods into the factory.  Your still stuck with O(n) just for the N classes though.  wxWidgets has such a system as the first to come to mind.

Comment: sorry, I thought it worth the comment to indicate another way, not intending to overly pick out *have*.

Comment: @Greg No problem, I thought you were meaning that I was saying that was the only way.

Answer (score 2):

That's not true. The `switch` statement will likely be compiled down to an O(1) jump table. Besides, once you get to *large* numbers of tiles, you should seriously consider moving to branching based on function changes- i.e., inheritance, function objects (including function pointers).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a map, which would work nicely using either `std::unordered_map` or `std::map`.  Since you mentioned that each class would inherit from a parent `Tile` class, you could set the type of the map to something like

```
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Tile> > tile_map;
```

Now you would setup the map by basically cycling through your indexes, and creating Tiles allocated on the heap, so that you could put tiles that are derived from `Tile` in your map.  For instance:

```
tile_map[0] = new Derived_Tile_A();
tile_map[1] = new Derived_Tile_B();
//... keep adding to map
```

Accessing the elements of the map would be done through the `int` type key-values, and would be done like a normal array-syntax, except that the return value would be an interator pointing to a node with a data-element type of `std::shared_ptr<Tile>`.  Once you dereference the iterator, the `shared_ptr` can be operated on with normal pointer defererencing syntax.

If you need to create a new object based on some condition, the best thing would be to look into a factory function that would be based on a `switch` statement and return a pointer to the proper derived type.  You would then call the factory function when creating your objects for the `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

You make an array of classes just as you would make any other array.

```
Tile tileClassArray[255];//makes an array of type classname with 255 members
```

With only ~1000 tiles in a level your best bet might be to just store the tiles in a array like the one above. This should be fine as long as the level size doesn't change often.

The class I would store would be say, of type Tile. For each type of tile make a derrived class with the properties of that tile. [inheritance](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/)

Comment: But is this the best/most efficient way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

C++ has very limited reflection capabilities, so what you're referring to is not directly possible.  Even so, if it were possible, the overhead would likely make it far less efficient than a switch statement.

The switch statement is going to be your best bet if performance is your goal.  Each case is implemented as a single jump statement in most machine languages, so your 255,000 checks will likely correspond to 255,000 instructions, which most modern processors can execute in less than 1ms.

Edit: See DeadMG's answer too, about jump tables.  That switch statement will probably be even more efficient than I described.